# In Powershell, how could I sort an array based on a substring within a string in the array?

Tags: arrays, powershell

My array contains `cpe:2.3:o:juniper:junos`, `cpe:2.3:h:hp`, and `cpe:2.3:a:microsoft:sql_server`. I'd like to alphabetically sort this array based on the 4th substring, `juniper`, `hp`, and `microsoft` in this case. Substrings are delimited by a colon `:`.

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366314/sort-an-array-based-on-a-substring-in-the-array-element), but I'm looking for a Powershell way to do this. I've tried creating a regex to sort, but that proved to be difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) cmdlet with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) that uses the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator to sort by the token of interest:

```bash
$array = 'cpe:2.3:o:juniper:junos', 'cpe:2.3:h:hp', 'cpe:2.3:a:microsoft:sql_server'

$array | Sort-Object { ($_ -split ':')[3] }
```

Output (sorted by the 4th field):

```
cpe:2.3:h:hp
cpe:2.3:o:juniper:junos
cpe:2.3:a:microsoft:sql_server
```